Does applying QR decomposition to each block matrix and then connecting vectors work?
We want to project the $d$-dimensional column vector $\mathbf x$ into the space created by the column vectors of the $d \times n$-dimensional matrix $V$. We tried to create a base matrix $V^\prime$ by applying QR decomposition to $V$, but we have a problem that the calculation of QR decomposition takes a long time because $d$ and $n$ are very large.
To solve this problem, we want to split the rows of $\mathbf x$ and $V$ in half, project them separately, and then match the results. That is, $\mathbf x$ is divided into $(d/2)$-dimensional column vectors $\mathbf x_1$ and $\mathbf x_2$, $V$ is divided into $(d/2)\times n$-dimensional matrices $V_1$ and $V_2$, and the base matrices $V_1^\prime$ and $V_2^\prime$ are used to project
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf x_1^\prime &={V_1^\prime}^ T\mathbf x_1,\\ 
\mathbf x_2^\prime&=V_2^\prime {V_2^\prime}^T\mathbf x_2 
\end{align}
$$using the base matrices $V_1^\prime$ and $V_2^\prime$ generated by applying QR decomposition to $V_1$ and $V_2$, respectively. At this time, $(\mathbf x_1^\prime, \mathbf x_2^\prime) = V^\prime {V^\prime}^T\mathbf x$ is established?

Hi and welcome to the MathOverflow: despite not being the downvoter, I must say your question cannot be classified as a research level, which is what this Q&A site is entirely devoted to. Why do not try to post it at our sister site Math.SE? It is devoted to all kind of mathematical questions (even very difficulties) and your one, perhaps after adding a little more context, will be surely better received.

Oh, I didn't realize that mathoverflow is a place where only research-oriented questions are asked. Thank you for your comment.
